# How to use Django template filters?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have Variable :

```
unit = 'BARS'
```

i pass this value into frontend using Django template

I want to get `'bar'`

I use `{{ unit|slice":4"|lower }}`

but it doesn't work .

Comment: try this `{{ unit|slice:3|lower }}`

Answer (score 0):

Add filter like this

```
{{ unit|lower|slice:'0:3' }}
```

For more information open link

https://www.djangotemplatetagsandfilters.com/filters/slice/